# Retrieving data from *.idx, *.dz files?

Tags: ios

I'm going to make an EN-VI,VI-EN dictionary app. I referenced this brilliant app [Dictionary app](https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/tra-cau-viet-anh-hoc-dich/id577933438?mt=8)

I extracted it's ipa file and saw some data like *.idx and *.dz files.

[image]

So how can I retrieve data from that files. Or someone can suggest me some sqlite database to using in app.

Comment: Dictionary files are copyrighted material. You cannot copy them from another application — that is **illegal**.

Comment: I just want to know how to read data from it. Beside, I just make app with practicing purpose

Comment: The format of these files really shouldn't concern you. If you need your own file format, make your own (or use SQLite, like you mentioned). If you need data to test with, copy some from a free source (not another developer's application!) or make some up.

Comment: Can you recommend some source?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary files are not necessarily copyrighted materials. I do agree with duskwuff that copying another application's data files is a bad idea, but you don't just have to roll your own solution.

The .dz / .idx files could be Dictd, or DICT, or StarDict, or ...

I suggest you take a look at [GoldenDict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldenDict), an open source dictionary and translation program, and the information related to the [DICT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICT) / [StarDict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarDict) formats. There are quite a few free dictionaries (including some or all of those used by the referenced Dictionary app). As for how to read the files, there is a github project called [StarDictReader](https://github.com/Centny/StarDictReader-lib) that may be a good starting point.